# Flutter How to prevent Text from blocking Gesture detection?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a 'Container' wrapped in a 'GestureDetector'. I've added 'Text' over the 'Container' at runtime and the 'Text' prevents parts of the 'Container' from detecting Gestures. How to prevent 'Text' from blocking Gesture detection?

```
class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyButtonState createState() => new _MyButtonState();
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new GestureDetector(
   onTapDown: myTapDown,
   child: new Container(),
  );
 }

void myTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
 showDialog(
   context: context,
   child: new Text(
    'SOME TEXT',
    textScaleFactor: 2.0,
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyPageState createState() => new _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new MyButton(),
    new Column(
      children: <Widget>[new Text('NAME'),new Text('NUMBER')],
      )
    ],
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Try to add the text inside the Container as a child. That should prevent it. I can't really help you any further than that as you have not added a code example of what you mean and tried :)

Comment: Can you share the code snippet?

Comment: I've added the code to the question. I need to add the Text/Column widget later as I will be rotating the 'MyButton' and dont't want to rotate the Text/Column with it.